# Настройка logrotate для openresty/nginx в centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos, логирование

Требуется настроить logrotate для openresty/nginx под centos 7.

Я подготовил конфигурацию, но она некорректная. В 00:00 текущий локальный access.log лог обнуляется, но не формируется новый лог файл за предыдущий день.

openresty/nginx работает под nobody

Вопрос как исправить проблему с формированием лога за предыдущий день.

```
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/*log {
    create 0644 nobody nobody
    daily
    rotate 365
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    dateext
    postrotate
            [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
    endscript
}
```

Права

```
ls -l
total 40
drwx------. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Feb 20 14:32 client_body_temp
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Mar  4 10:16 conf
drwx------. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Feb 20 14:32 fastcgi_temp
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Feb 20 14:15 html
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Mar  4 10:28 logs
drwx------. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Feb 20 14:32 proxy_temp
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Feb 20 14:15 sbin
drwx------. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Feb 20 14:32 scgi_temp
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Feb 20 14:15 tapset
drwx------. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Feb 20 14:32 uwsgi_temp
```

---

```
ls -l
total 94928
-rw-r--r--. 1 nobody nobody 67091841 Mar  4 10:35 access.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 nobody nobody 30100415 Mar  4 10:34 error.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root          6 Mar  4 10:28 nginx.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 nobody nobody        0 Feb 25 14:44 test_access.log
```

Процессы

```
root     30438  0.0  0.0  37348  1608 ?        Ss   10:28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
nobody   30439  0.0  0.0  39908  3288 ?        S    10:28   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     30591  0.0  0.0 112712   960 pts/1    S+   10:36   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

P.S.
Проблему исправил. Обновил конфиг с учетом комментариев Данила, а также исправил опечатку в logrotate.d/nginx файле в пути - была пропущена буква s в /log/ 
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/*log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, NGINX продолжает писать в уже переименованный файл, так как не получает должный сигнал о том что лог нужно открыть заново.

За это отвечает `postrotate`. Из конфига стандартного NGINX:

```
postrotate
        [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
endscript
```

Попробуйте заменить на это, изменив путь к PID файлу.

Если после ротации даже не создаётся пустой файл, значит директива `create` не верна и не позволяет этому пользователя создавать файлы в директории. Проверьте что `nobody` можно создать файл в `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/log/`:

```
sudo -u nobody touch /usr/local/openresty/nginx/log/test.txt
```

Comment: sudo -u nobody touch /usr/local/openresty/nginx/log/test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/local/openresty/nginx/log/test.txt’: No such file or directory
Вопрос - как правильно настроить права ?

Comment: Проблему решил. Была опечатка в конфиге logrotate/nginx . Вместо usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/ было прописано usr/local/openresty/nginx/log/